# Recursively determine child structure

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

I have created the following class (Simplified):

```
public class ClassItem{
        //Sub-Groups
        public List<ClassItem> Children { get; set; }
        public Int64 MaxChilds { get; set; }
        //Properties
        .........
}
```

Now I am trying to get the maximum Children in each branch to the upper level with a recursive method. To clarify this somewhat, Say that I have the following structure:

```
- ClassItem 1                        (5)
    - ClassItem 1.1                  (1)
        - ClassItem 1.1.1            (0)
    - ClassItem 1.2                  (0)
    - ClassItem 1.3                  (3)
        - ClassItem 1.3.1            (0)
        - ClassItem 1.3.2            (0)
        - ClassItem 1.3.3            (2)
            - ClassItem 1.3.3.1      (0)
            - ClassItem 1.3.3.2      (0)
    - ClassItem 1.4                  (5)
        - ClassItem 1.4.1            (0)
        - ClassItem 1.4.2            (0)
        - ClassItem 1.4.3            (0)
        - ClassItem 1.4.4            (0)
        - ClassItem 1.4.5            (0)
```

The numbers between brackets is the maximum of; number of children or the numbers of the children within its children in any of its own branches.

I tried a lot of things, but it does not seem to function correctly. What I now have is the following:

```
private void FindMaxChilds(ClassItem classItem, ref Int64 horizontalMaxLevels) {
            //Count horizontal for each child
            if (horizontalMaxLevels < classItem.Children.Count) {
                horizontalMaxLevels = classItem.Children.Count;
            }

            foreach (ClassItem cci in classItem.Children) {
                FindMaxLevels(cci, ref horizontalMaxLevels);
            }

            classItem.MaxChilds = horizontalMaxLevels;
        }
```

Can someone help me on the way to get there?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ClassItem 1 (11)`? Which is the sum of 1 + 3 + 2 + 5.

Comment: No, the maximum number of children in any of its subbranches is 5:
1.1 has 1, 1.2 has 0, 1.3 has 3, 1.4 has 5 and 1 itselve has 4 children. (I do not mean all the children on the deepest level!)

Comment: Then why is 1.4 (5) then? Because all 1.4`s children have 0 child. If I understand it correctly it should be 1.4 (0).

Comment: Yes but 1.4 itselve has 5 children

Comment: I specified the question somewhat clearer

Comment: Well, I think your model is broken. 1 (5) because 1.4 (5), but 1.3 (3) because 1.3.3 (2)? You sometimes take the max of the children, and sometimes the number of children.

Comment: The model is not broken, i take the maximum of its own children AND the maximum of the children's children.

Comment: @ArthurRey - I think you've nailed the requirement - The max of either the count of the children or the max value of any of the children.

Comment: Please edit your question using @Enigmativity words.

Comment: @ArthurRey - I already updated the question earlier, to make it more comprehensive..

Comment: @Sliver2009, I think my solution should work for you.

Comment: @OrelEraki I upvoted you and used your answer to create a property instead of a function as it is - if I understand it correctly - what the `MaxChilds` property is meant for.

Comment: @ArthurRey, Feel free, I wanted to do it myself, but than again, he didn't gave us many input (at that time of the post creation), so i preferred just to return an int instead of the void, and let the OP update and tweak it to his disposal. By maybe make it a private method inside `ClassItem` and then using it inside the MaxChildren getter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've split it into, DirectChildren, and the output of my children childrens.

```
public static int MaxDirectChidrenPerItem(ClassItem item)
{
    if (item.Children == null || item.Children.Count == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int directChildrenCount = item.Children.Count();
    int descendantMaxCount = item.Children.Max(child => MaxDirectChidrenPerItem(child));
    return Math.Max(directChildrenCount, descendantMaxCount);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, only had to include writing to the property. I was just staring blind on the recursion for to long :-)!

Comment: @Sliver2009 Instead of a method that writes the returning value to the property, consider using the property itself as a get-ter. You can find the example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using @OrelEraki's answer, I think you don't need a method but you can wrap everything in one property:

```
public class ClassItem
{
    public List<ClassItem> Children { get; set; }
    public Int64 MaxChildren
    { 
        get
        {
            if (this.Children == null || this.Children.Count == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int directChildrenCount = this.Children.Count();
            int descendantMaxCount = this.Children.Max(child => child.MaxChildren);
            return Math.Max(directChildrenCount, descendantMaxCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a very nice/smart solution, to include it in a property! However, I wanted a method, hence i accepted @OrelEraki 's answer

Comment: As long as you got your solution :)

Comment: Can you change item.  to this. ? I also wanted to try this solution, and saw that issue!

Comment: Well spotted. Updated it.